# Getting: Type 'Service_ValetApp' does not conform to protocol 'App' In Xcode 12.5

Tags: swiftui, protocols, xcode12.5

I get a Type 'Service_ValetApp' does not conform to protocol 'App' and I get a fix from the compiler: Do you want to add protocol stubs? Even though I have an init() already in the file. This looks like a bug to me. If anyone has seen this before I would appreciate any and all insights.

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct Service_ValetApp: App {
    
    
    @Binding var isInitializing: Bool
    
    init(isInitializing: Binding<Bool>) {
        
        
        self._isInitializing = isInitializing
        
    }
    
   
 
    
   
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            
            MotherView(isInitializing: self.$isInitializing).environmentObject(ViewRouter())
            
          
            
            
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Type type `App` needs to have an initializer that takes zero arguments:

```
init() {
  //content here
}
```

You have a argument in your initializer:

```
init(isInitializing: Binding<Bool>) {
```

The system is calling `init` and wouldn't know what to pass for `isInitializing`.

Secondly, you have a `@Binding` in your `App` -- `@Binding` is used with child views, but this is the top-most parent app component.

Perhaps you meant to use `@State` with a default value instead:

```
@main struct Service_ValetApp: App {
    @State var isInitializing : Bool = true
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            MotherView(isInitializing: self.$isInitializing)
                .environmentObject(ViewRouter())
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: jnpdx Thank you for the answer and the insight. Very much appreciate.